# Delete Wordpress Post from my .csv URL list

Tags: mysql, wordpress, csv, post, sql-delete

I've got a .csv file with a list of URL I want to delete in my wordpress blog (about 3000 URLs)

Which is the faster way to delete it? I suppose a SQL query, or something like this...

Answer (score 1):

Wise WordPress admins employ plugins for this kind of purpose, rather than hacking away at the MySQL database behind the WordPress installation.

This plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-delete/ claims to accept a bunch of URLs to delete.

(Don't forget to back up your installation first.)